# How to add if..else conditional statements to the db query builder of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder, laravel-excel

I have a export method in Laravel 5.8 for exporting some results from `oders` table:

```
public static function getAllData()
    {
       $records = DB::table('orders as t1')
            ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
            ->leftjoin('members as t3', 't2.pay_creator_id', '=', 't3.mbr_usr_id')
            ->where('t2.pay_confirm', 1)
            ->where('t1.ord_status','completed')
            ->orWhere('t1.ord_status','processing')
            ->select('t1.ord_id','t1.ord_date','t1.ord_total','t3.mbr_mobile','t3.mbr_name','t3.mbr_family')
            ->get(); 
       return $records;
    }
```

So it works fine and clean but I do need to add one more column for checking if the order payment type is by **wallet** or **paid directly**.

So every payment has a `pay_type_id` and if it is set to **`189`**, then it should print **Paid With Wallet** otherwise print **Paid Online** as the appended column.

But the problem is, I don't know how to check this if..else condition in this method...

So if you know, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `case` to do if else condition

for example like this

```
    public static function getAllData()
    {
        $records = DB::table('orders as t1')
        ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
        ->leftjoin('members as t3', 't2.pay_creator_id', '=', 't3.mbr_usr_id')
        ->where('t2.pay_confirm', 1)
        ->where('t1.ord_status', 'completed')
        ->orWhere('t1.ord_status', 'processing')
        ->select(DB::raw("case when pay_type_id=189 then 'Paid With Wallet' else 'Paid Online' end as your_column_name"),'t1.ord_id', 't1.ord_date', 't1.ord_total', 't3.mbr_mobile', 't3.mbr_name', 't3.mbr_family')
        ->get();
        return $records;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199105/how-to-subtract-two-columns-from-each-other-when-using-case-expression

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
->select(DB::raw('IF(pay_type_id=189,"Paid With Wallet","Paid Online as") as order_payment_type'))
```